# Prove that if $n^2$ is odd then $n$ is odd?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

Here is my solution:
I assume $n^2$ is odd 
then I put $n^2$= $(2x-1)^2$, now I am taking root square for both sides:
$\sqrt{(n^2)}$ = $\sqrt{(2x-1)^2}$ $\Rightarrow$ $n = (2x-1)$ $\Rightarrow$ $n$ is odd since R.H.S has -1 of an even number.

Is my solution a good proof?

Comment: You've assumed what you are trying to prove. You only start knowing the $n^2=2m-1$ for some $m$. Also, do you know that $n$ is not negative?

Comment: I assumed $n^2$ is odd, and I got n is odd, this is a proof by construction? is not it ?

Comment: You assumed more than that $n^2$ was odd, you assumed that $n^2$ is the square of an odd number, which is really what you are trying to prove.

Comment: OOh, you are right, yes

Comment: Worth noting: “If $n^2$ is odd, then $n$ is odd” is not a true theorem for $n$ a real number. For example, let $n=\sqrt3$. Then $n^2$ is odd, but $n$ is not odd. It must also be assumed that $n$ is an integer, so somewhere in your proof you will have to use that fact.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not a correct proof because if $n^2$ is odd, then it doesn't necessarily take the form $(2k - 1)^2$. In fact, that's what you are required to prove.

Your assumption should be $\exists$ $k \in \mathbb N$, such that $n^2 = 2k - 1$.

However, this isn't a very fruitful approach. The classical solution to this is to work by contraposition.

Suppose that $n$ is even, then we can write $n = 2k$. Then, $n^2 = 4k^2 = 2(2k^2)$, so it is even. This gives that if $n^2$ is odd, then $n$ is odd.

Comment: how 'this gives that if $n^2$ is odd then $n$ is odd'

Comment: @TandeeHolwa As he said, by contraposition.

Comment: As. Entitled, it is a proof of the contrapositive, high is equivalent.

Comment: @TandeeHolwa: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition

Comment: OK, I did not notice 'Contraposition' word :)

Comment: I have another question what is the best resources for understanding NP / P / NP-Hard Problem? deeply

Comment: @TandeeHolwa: As I said elsewhere, I am serious when I say you have to learn first-order logic properly, since it is fundamental to everything else and would make things like proofs by contradiction or contraposition or whatever completely evident and trivial. And certainly you cannot understand or reason about NP problems if you do not have a firm grasp of first-order logic, because they involve a significant level of quantifier complexity.

Answer (score 4):

You only need to note if $n$ is even, $n^2$ is even !

Comment: This is technically accurate but there's no explanation at all of why it's accurate or how you would actually use this in a proof.

Answer (score 2):

You accidentally assume the conclusion... what you really know is that $n^2 = 2x-1$ for some integer $x$. Look at prime factorizations instead. How many factors of $2$ does $n^2$ have? Then how many could $n$ have?

Answer (score 2):

To complete a proof differently from the one others have suggested.

Suppose $n^2$ is odd, then $n^2=2m-1$ and $(n+1)^2=2(m-n)$

Now $2$ is prime and $2\mid (n+1)^2$ so $2\mid n+1$ therefore $n+1=2r$ (for some integer $r$) whence $n=2r-1$ and $n$ is odd.

But the easier route is to show that the square of an even number is even, so an odd number can't be the square of an even number. So if an odd number is a square it must be the square of an odd number.

Answer (score 1):

on contrary suppose that $n$ is even and $n=2k$

So $n^2=(2k)^2=4k^2$

$\implies 2|n^2$

which shows that $n^2$ is even, which contradicts the fact that $n^2$ is odd.

Comment: so why if n^2 is not even then n is odd, what you did is prove for even assumption, but how did you generalize it to odd, is it because the opposite here 'only' odd

Comment: Dear an integer can be either even or odd. We have to show that n is odd, So I assuming n even and showed the contradiction.

Comment: @TandeeHolwa This is a proof of the [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition), which is equivalent to your statement.

Comment: @André3000 This is a proof by contradiction, not contrapositive