# If $n$ is even, then $n^2$ is even when n is an integer (proof by contraposition)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

Okay so we did this question in class today. When my teacher wrote it out on the board, I pointed out that I thought he was assuming the premise. After class we talked about it for a while, but I'm not sure if he quite understood my concern.

We're trying to use the contrapositive to prove that:

> if $n$ is even, then $n^2$ will also be even, where n is an integer

Since any integer that isn't even is odd, the contrapositive statement reads:

> if $n^2$ is odd, then $n$ is odd, where n is an integer

To begin: we assume that

> $n^2$ = $(2k+1)^2$

since we know an odd integer squared is odd.

After simplifying, we have

> $n = 2k + 1$

so n must be odd

Therefore, by contraposition, the proof is complete.

To me this is a blatantly circular argument, and this feeling is confirmed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1328357/prove-that-if-n2-is-odd-then-n-is-odd). I've been thinking that maybe because the initial goal was to show [$n$ is even --> $n^2$ is even], then its okay to make the assumption about the result of squaring an odd number. To me it still seems like you shouldn't be able to make an argument like that, even if it's hidden inside a contrapositive statement.

Thanks

Comment: I agree with you. That proof is not correct. (And why bother with the contrapositive statement to begin with? Just say that if $n=2k$, then $n^2 = 2 \cdot 2k^2$.)

Comment: Assuming that $n^2=(2k+1)^2$ indeed seems a little circular. One should begin with $n^2=2k+1$ and conclude that if $n=2l$ is even, this is a contradiction.

Comment: Not only is the argument circular, it is not even correct. The "simplification" from $n^2=(2k+1)^2$ to $n=2k+1$ is invalid. For example, $(-3)^2 = (2(1)+1)^2$, but $-3$ is not equal to $2(1)+1$. The correct next step is that $|n|=|2k+1|$. But that argument assumes that every odd square is the square of an odd number... which is what you claim to want to prove.

Comment: A correct argument would be if $n^2=2k+1$ then $n^2-1$ is even so $(n+1)(n-1)$ is even which tells us that $n+1$ or $n-1$ is even, but in both cases this means $n$ is odd.

Comment: The error is already explained in the accepted answer in the post you linked.

Answer (score 0):

It follows from the fact that $A\implies B$ and $\lnot B\implies \lnot A$ have the same truth values in the truth table.

So if you have proven that $\lnot B \implies \lnot A$ then $A\implies B$.

However, the argument is wrong.

It should read $n^2=2k-1$ and
$(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1=2k-1+2n+1=2(k-n)$.

To prove this you need the fact that if $q| p^2$ then $q|p$ for $q$ prime.
$2$ is prime and $2|(n+1)^2$ so $2|n+1$. By definition $2l=n+1 \implies n=2l-1$.